# xamarin.forms binding to class property not working

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding

In my XamarinForms project I am trying to bind a label text to a property of a class.  when I pass in the object to my view the label is not being populated.  can someone see what I am doing wrong?

In my view model I have

```
    class ManagerLevelPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private UserSelections _MyUserSelections;
    public UserSelections MyUserSelections
    {
        get { return _MyUserSelections; }
        set {
                _MyUserSelections = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
    }

        public ManagerLevelPageViewModel(UserSelections _temp)
    {
        MyUserSelections = _temp;
        MyUserSelections.selectedClientName = _temp.selectedClientName;
        //myUserSelections = _myUserSelections;
        //SetValues();
    }
```

here is the class

```
public class UserSelections
{
    public int selectedClientId { get; set; }
    public string selectedClientName { get; set; }
    public string selectedClientShortCode { get; set; }

    public decimal selectedClientPL { get; set; }

    public string TopdayIdentifier { get; set; }
}
```

here is the view.cs

```
        ManagerLevelPageViewModel vm;

    public ManagerLevelPage (UserSelections _myUserSelections)
    {
        vm = new ManagerLevelPageViewModel(_myUserSelections);
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = vm;

        DownloadData();
    }
```

lastly here is the xaml

```
                <Label Text="{Binding MyUserSelections.ClientName}"/>
```

notify property changed

```
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: UserSelections does not have a property called "ClientName"

Comment: talk about an oversight.... thanks!!!  it works now!

Comment: @Jason so for a different property, when I update the value in the viewmodel, the label is not being updated.  any ideas?  does it have something to do with iNotifypropertychanged?  - i updated my code above to show code for propchang

Comment: <Label Text="{Binding MyUserSelections.selectedClientPL}"/>

Comment: in my viewmodel             decimal? calc = ViewManagerByAcct.Sum(x => x.CalcPnl);
            MyUserSelections.selectedClientPL = calc;

Comment: yes, UserSelections needs to implement INPC

Comment: @Jason but aren't I doing that. It doesn't seem to be hitting code for property changed.  do you see why.... sorry for all the questions

Comment: no, the UserSelections class does NOT implement INPC

Comment: works... thanks!!!!